# Redirect after User Activation

Tags: users, redirect, buddypress, activation

I am using BuddyPress 2 registration and activation for three different sites with my own registration form.
To know where the user has registered, I add the user meta key `registered_from` at registration.
Is there a way to redirect the user after activation to the site where he registered?

Answer (score 1):

Paste this code in your [`bp-custom.php`](http://codex.buddypress.org/extending-buddypress/bp-custom-php/) file or, if you prefer, your active theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'bp_core_activated_user', 'wpse_70289_activated_user_redirect' );

function wpse_70289_activated_user_redirect( $user_id ) {
    $registered_from = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'registered_from', true );
    wp_redirect( $registered_from );
}
```

I haven't tested this code myself yet, but it should work just fine.

#### References:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

Comment: Thank you.Its not working here, but you gave me a good direction.

Comment: @Paul - If it's not working, you could try using `wp_safe_redirect()` instead of `wp_redirect()`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Is my answer *still* not working? Is there any way I can improve it?